# need clarification on error "Can't use string ("package") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"

Tags: perl

Here is my code.

```
my $hash1 = $hash0->{unknown}{unknown};
while ( my ( $var, $hash2 ) = each %$hash1 ) {
    ...
}
```

Am hitting the error `"Can't use string ("package") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use"` when I try to access `my $hash1 = $hash0->{unknown}{unknown}` from the below hash.

```
print Dumper $hash0;

$VAR1 = 
bless( {
    'branch' => bless( {
         'lib/sample/sp.pm' => bless( {
             'branch' => bless( {
                 'lib/sample/sp.pm'=>     bless( {
                     'sample::sp' => '1'
                 }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' )
             }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' ),
         'branch' => $VAR1->{'branch'}{'lib/sample/sp.pm'}{'branch'}
         }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' )
                     }, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' ),
'main' => bless( {}, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' ),
'main' => $VAR1->{'main'}
}, 'DBM::Deep::Hash' );
```

I went through many forums and my understanding on this error is, will hit this when     `$hash->{unknown}{unknown}` has a string instead of hash (I am dereferencing `$hash1` in next step of my code). But I don't see any string values('package' as indicated in error message) in the hash but still it complains.

Can some one please help me in understanding the issue.

Comment: the chances that `package` shows up in the error message but not in the Dumper output are practically-zero ; maybe you need to Dumper another variable; maybe try `use Carp::Always;`

Comment: Your dumped hash shows the key `main` twice. Are you sure you copied'n'pasted it correctly?

Comment: Have copied the hash correctly, wondered seeing duplicate keys.

Comment: Which DBM::Deep version?

Comment: This looks like a screwy problem, with deep-self-referential and duplicate-keyed hashes, I hope the solution reveals something interesting!
@sunil: Which line does the strict refs error occur in, is it the my declaration line or the while() line? Also, could you give us a bit more context, is the $hash0 supposed to be an object of DBM::Deep::Hash? How is it created?

Comment: DBM::Deep version: 1.0014

Comment: Error is coming for the first line of my code not in while statement. And it is supposed to be a DBM::Deep object.

Comment: regarding duplicate keys in hash, if we observe the hash it has two objects, the third key in the hash I have posted above is a separate object.

Comment: Now I know from where 'package' is coming.

Comment: $hash0->unknown is giving us value 'package'. And it is very strange, can some one point out us to exact reason why we are getting 'package' when we try to access $hash0->unknown. We have structure of hash0 and there is no key by name unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not mention `use strict`. With `strict` in effect, according to your code, `$hash1` is undefined and thus cannot be coerced into a hash. One option is to use `each %{$hash1 || {}}` if you must code it this way.

Comment: Thanks will try this and let you know.